# Angular : How to always reload a URL but ignore fragments ? (with RunGuardsAndResolvers ?)

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-resolver

I 'always' want to reload my resolver and only ignoring the reload when a fragment is set (ex: URL/xxx?yyy#FRAGMENTHERE)

Am I missing something or is it not possible in Angular ?

Here is what I tried :

in app-routing-module.ts

```
...
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
...
```

in XXX-routing-module.ts

Test 1:

```
...
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' as RunGuardsAndResolvers,
...
```

This one is not working because when a fragment changes, the resolver is called

Test 2,3,4:

```
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'pathParamsOrQueryParamsChange' as RunGuardsAndResolvers,
```

```
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange' as RunGuardsAndResolvers,
```

```
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsChange' as RunGuardsAndResolvers,
```

Thoses ones are not working because if I'm trying to reload on the same URL it's not calling the resolver

PS : The navigate looks like this

```
this.router.navigate([], {
     queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
     queryParams: {
         ProgramState: ProgramState.Reading,
         Session: 0,
     }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any solution to your problem? I have some issue  similar to yours

Comment: I wish I found something but no, for now I use a workaround : I added a variable "ForceReload" and the value is Math.random()